# Declare and populate a hash table in one step in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, initialization, lookup-tables, hashref

Currently when I want to build a look-up table I use:

```
my $has_field = {};
map { $has_field->{$_} = 1 } @fields;
```

Is there a way I can do inline initialization in a single step? (i.e. populate it at the same time I'm declaring it?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use your map to create a list then drop into a hash reference like:

```
my $has_field = { map { $_ => 1 } @fields };
```

Answer (score 3):

Update: sorry, this doesn't do what you want exactly, as you still have to declare $has_field first.

You could use a hash slice:

```
@{$has_field}{@fields} = (1)x@fields;
```

The right hand side is using the `x` operator to repeat one by the scalar value of @fields (i.e. the number of elements in your array). Another option in the same vein:

```
@{$has_field}{@fields} = map {1} @fields;
```

Comment: This works correctly but still requires declaring `$has_field` separately when using `use strict;`. It's still a good trick to know though.

Answer (score 2):

Where I've tested it [smart match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) can be 2 to 5 times as fast as creating a lookup hash and testing for the value *once*. So unless you're going to reuse the hash a good number of times, it's best to do a smart match:

```
if ( $cand_field ~~ \@fields ) { 
   do_with_field( $cand_field );
}
```

It's a good thing to remember that since 5.10, Perl now has a way *native* to ask "is this untested value any of these known values", it's *smart match*.

Comment: Thanks for this great tip.  I'm definitely going to put that to use.